# Received duplicate connection from <nil>

Tags: hyperledger

I am trying to set up a PBFT network with 4 nodes, on separate machines. In the `core.yaml`, I change the following params: `peer.id` are vp0-vp3, `peer.address` is the IP and port of the node, `peer.validator.consensus.plugin` is pbft, and `peer.discovery.rootnode` is the vp0 node's IP and port. When I start up the nodes, I see warnings and errors in the nodes (I start them in vp0 -> vp3 order)

vp0:

```
13:53:34.091 [main] serve -> INFO 032 Starting peer with id=name:"vp0" , network id=dev, address=172.31.45.37:30303, discovery.rootnode=, validator=true
13:53:34.091 [rest] StartOpenchainRESTServer -> INFO 033 Initializing the REST service on 0.0.0.0:5000, TLS is disabled.
13:53:39.833 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> INFO 034 Registering connection from <nil>
13:53:44.393 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> WARN 035 Received duplicate connection from <nil>, switching to new connection
13:56:45.008 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> WARN 036 Received duplicate connection from <nil>, switching to new connection
```

vp1:

```
13:53:38.827 [main] serve -> INFO 032 Starting peer with id=name:"vp1" , network id=dev, address=172.31.46.226:30303, discovery.rootnode=172.31.45.37:30303, validator=true
13:53:38.828 [rest] StartOpenchainRESTServer -> INFO 033 Initializing the REST service on 0.0.0.0:5000, TLS is disabled.
13:53:39.829 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> INFO 034 Registering connection from <nil>
13:53:45.832 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> WARN 035 Received duplicate connection from <nil>, switching to new connection
13:56:50.832 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> WARN 036 Received duplicate connection from <nil>, switching to new connection
13:56:51.007 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> WARN 037 Received duplicate connection from <nil>, switching to new connection
13:56:51.007 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 038 Error handling message: Peer FSM failed while handling message (DISC_HELLO): current state: created, error: transition canceled with error: Error registering Handler: Duplicate Handler error: {name:"vp3"  172.31.43.65:30303 VALIDATOR }
```

vp2:

```
13:53:43.370 [main] serve -> INFO 032 Starting peer with id=name:"vp2" , network id=dev, address=172.31.37.75:30303, discovery.rootnode=172.31.45.37:30303, validator=true
13:53:43.370 [rest] StartOpenchainRESTServer -> INFO 033 Initializing the REST service on 0.0.0.0:5000, TLS is disabled.
13:53:44.372 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> INFO 034 Registering connection from <nil>
13:53:45.816 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> WARN 035 Received duplicate connection from <nil>, switching to new connection
13:56:50.376 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> WARN 036 Received duplicate connection from <nil>, switching to new connection
13:56:50.994 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> WARN 037 Received duplicate connection from <nil>, switching to new connection
13:56:50.994 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 038 Error handling message: Peer FSM failed while handling message (DISC_HELLO): current state: created, error: transition canceled with error: Error registering Handler: Duplicate Handler error: {name:"vp3"  172.31.43.65:30303 VALIDATOR }
```

vp3:

```
13:56:44.000 [main] serve -> INFO 035 Starting peer with id=name:"vp3" , network id=dev, address=172.31.43.65:30303, discovery.rootnode=172.31.45.37:30303, validator=true
13:56:44.001 [rest] StartOpenchainRESTServer -> INFO 036 Initializing the REST service on 0.0.0.0:5000, TLS is disabled.
13:56:45.002 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> INFO 037 Registering connection from <nil>
13:56:50.388 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> WARN 038 Received duplicate connection from <nil>, switching to new connection
13:56:50.831 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> WARN 039 Received duplicate connection from <nil>, switching to new connection
13:56:51.006 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> WARN 03a Received duplicate connection from <nil>, switching to new connection
13:56:51.006 [consensus/util] RegisterChannel -> WARN 03b Received duplicate connection from <nil>, switching to new connection
13:56:51.006 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 03c Error handling message: Peer FSM failed while handling message (DISC_HELLO): current state: created, error: transition canceled with error: Error registering Handler: Duplicate Handler error: {name:"vp2"  172.31.37.75:30303 VALIDATOR }
13:56:51.006 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 03d Error handling message: Peer FSM failed while handling message (DISC_HELLO): current state: created, error: transition canceled with error: Error registering Handler: Duplicate Handler error: {name:"vp1"  172.31.46.226:30303 VALIDATOR }
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several related issues on github

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/issues/1468
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/issues/685

I had similar problem with Hyperledger Fabric deployment in Amazon (1 Membership, 4 Validation peers deployed on separate VMs, PBFT consensus, security enabled).

There were 2 scenarios when “Peer FSM failed while handling message” error message was in the log:

1. If one of EC2 instances with Validation Peers was stopped and then started again.
2. If I was trying to add new node to the cluster. Even if it was completely new VM with similar Fabric configuration and new peer id (id was not used before in this cluster)

It was possible to reproduce this issue only when Validation Peer was added to the cluster for the first time. 
The second time, for example if “peer” process was terminated(`Ctrl+C`) and then started again, Validation Peer had no issues at start time.

I'm still looking for a reason why “Received duplicate connection from ” message is in log files for all Validation peers. At least this warning doesn’t cause any visible problems to the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but after updating `hyperledger/fabric` to the new version (it was commit `eb7605ea9a50f10ae7e275811b61c5b43ec239f2`) it is starting to work.

Peers are successfully connected to each other (with default settings in `pbft consensus` plugin) in the following order:

```
vp3 -> vp2 -> vp1 -> vp0
```

(vp3 connected to vp2 etc).